# How to pause background Music in ios

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-player

I am playing video in my application

```
_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
_player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, frame.size.width,frame.size.height - 130);
_player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
_player.fullscreen = NO;
[_player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
_player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[_player setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaUrl]];
[_player play];
```

And i have to do some configuration -

1- If device is silent then play video with full volume.
2- If device is playing any music in another application then have to pause the background songs and play again when video play completed.

So i searched a lot then found following solutions -

For 1-

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
```

its working perfectly when device is silent.then its playing in full volume.

For 2- Both background song and Video audio playing both, I am doing following -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}
```

But its not working, its stoping background music but not playing again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because `viewWillDisappear` is not called when the app goes to background.

Furthermore:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: nil];
```

does not work to avoid background music once it has been activated.